# use NextRouter outside of React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

I have a custom hook that will check whether you are logged in, and redirect you to the login page if you are not. Here is a pseudo implementation of my hook that assumes that you are not logged in:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function useAuthentication() {

  if (!AuthenticationStore.isLoggedIn()) {
    const router = useRouter();
    router.push('/login'); 
  }
}
```

But when I use this hook, I get the following error:

> Error: No router instance found. you should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app. https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/no-router-instance

I checked the link in the error, but this is not really helpful because it just tells me to move the `push` statement to my render function.

I also tried this:

```js
// My functional component
export default function SomeComponent() {

  const router = useRouter();
  useAuthentication(router);

  return <>...</>
}

// My custom hook
export default function useAuthentication(router) {

  if (!AuthenticationStore.isLoggedIn()) {
    router.push('/login');
  }
}
```

But this just results in the same error.

Is there any way to allow routing outside of React components in Next.js?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error happens because `router.push` is getting called on the server during SSR on the page's first load. A possible workaround would be to extend your custom hook to call `router.push` inside a `useEffect`'s callback, ensuring the action only happens on the client.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function useAuthentication() {
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!AuthenticationStore.isLoggedIn()) {
            router.push('/login'); 
        }
    }, [router]);
}
```

Then use it in your component:

```js
import useAuthentication from '../hooks/use-authentication' // Replace with your path to the hook

export default function SomeComponent() {
    useAuthentication();

    return <>...</>;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`import Router from 'next/router'`

Comment: Maybe explain why this works... e.g. difference between importing named and default exports.

Comment: This is an instance of  the `next/router`. Not really the named vs default import. { useRouter } is a hook/function that you import.

Comment: Not a solution, same exception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325145/import-router-from-next-router-is-it-ok

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17046

Comment: Does this keep state?

Answer (score 4):

If you stumbled upon this while searching on accessing nextjs router outside of react components without using any hooks, you can refer to this answer on a GitHub issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17046

extract from the above reference

```js
import Router from 'next/router'

//Add following line within the required code block
Router.push("/")
```

Answer (score 2):

create a HOC which will wrap your page component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';

export default function UseAuthentication() {
 return () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!AuthenticationStore.isLoggedIn()) router.push("/login");
    }, []); 
// yous should also add isLoggedIn in array of dependancy if the value is not a function

    return <Component {...arguments} />;
  };
}
```

main component

```
function SomeComponent() {


  return <>...</>
}
export default UseAuthentication(SomeComponent)
```

Comment: This results in the same error: `Error: No router instance found. You should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.`