# import Router from 'next/router' is it ok?

Tags: next.js, router, next-router

Next.js documentation mentions two ways to access the `router` object: `useRouter` for functional components and `withRouter` for class-based components.

However, it does not mention something I came across a few times which is the `Router` object accessed as follows, for example:

```
import Router from 'next/router'

Router.push("/")
```

Is it correct to use `Router` in this way? Why doesn't Next.js documentation mention it?

Comment: here is one of their examples
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/1d643eb6e1cc57faaecf02e6c3c5e1bb463b2027/examples/with-loading/pages/_app.js#L1 but in their docs they use useRouter
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents

Comment: The difference is that in that example ([github.com/vercel/next.js/...](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/1d643eb6e1cc57faaecf02e6c3c5e1bb463b2027/examples/with-loading/pages/_app.js#L1)) the Router is used outside of the component, so [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) or [withRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#withrouter) can not be used.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess the main suggestion to **not** use Router.push() or Router.pathname directly from the object itself is because of the way Next.js serves the applications. When you're trying to do:

```
import Router from 'next/router';

const HomePage = () => {
  console.log(Router.pathname);

  return (
    <div>hi</div>
  )
}
```

You will receive an error with: `You should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app`. This is because of the way next/router works with SSR.

You could however put this in an `useEffect` and it will work... but that's hacky and you will probably run into issues in the future.

Both `useRouter` and `withRouter` are Next.js their solution to this problem. They are both build so they can work with SSR and CSR. So my suggestion is just to use one of these, they work great .

Comment: see also https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18522: "...important for concurrent features..."