# How can i use router.push with shallow routing in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am beginner in next js.I know how next js routing works but shallow routing not working as i expected in my project. Please share a helpful resources about it except official documentation

Comment: SO is not a coaching site.

Comment: What exactly is not working as expected? Can you provide some code and clarify what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this post:

[import Router from 'next/router' is it ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325145/import-router-from-next-router-is-it-ok/64353990#64353990)

Here is a similar question about this topic. Otherwise I would really suggest reading the docs of Next.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Comment: Thank you. I understood routing but shallow routing not working as i expected. in my project

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
import { withRouter } from "next/router";
import Router from "next/router";
```

```
const ComponentName= ({ router }) => {
//.......
Router.replace(`/`); // here will be location

}
export default withRouter(ComponentName);
```

if still not work, then try with `uesEffect()`

```
  useEffect(() => {

    // you initial function

  }, [router]);
```