# What is the difference between NextJs Singleton Router instance vs useRouter()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

I am using NextJS in my application. In that, for routing, we make use of the following:

```
import React from "react";
import {useRouter} from "next/router";

const IndexPage: React.FC = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.replace('/home');
  }, []);

  return null;
};
```

This is what even the documentation recommends to follow. They make use of the  useRouter hook to tap into the router instance and do stuff with it.

I have been using an alternative to the above approach. There is a singleton router instance that is the default export of the next/router file. It allows me to do routing stuff without tapping into the router instance using the hook.

```
import React from "react";
import Router from "next/router";

const IndexPage: React.FC = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    Router.replace('/home');
  }, []);

  return null;
};
```

I like the second approach more. But, I see no documentation for this on the NextJs site. Not sure if this is the correct way to do routing. I want to know what is the difference between these 2 approaches and will second approach lead to any problems in the future.

Comment: Testing would be easier if you can inject the router through a context

Comment: Does this answer your question: [import Router from 'next/router' is it ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325145/import-router-from-next-router-is-it-ok)? Also worth a read https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18522.

Comment: Yep. Thanks. This helps.