# use router replace in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm learning nextjs but got an error,

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
export default function Auth() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const root = router.query.auth;

  if (root !== "signin" && root !== "signup") {
    router.replace("/404");
  }

  return <div>form</div>;
}
```

[image: result]

can someone explain to me why I got an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [use NextRouter outside of React component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66268808/1870780)? Essentially, you'll need to call `router.replace` inside a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't Import router, In next if you wanna handle routing best is do on serverside it will solve your issue.